# Сортировка списка файлов по размеру с помощью Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка, администрирование

задача банальная для людей разбирающихся в программировании.
В организации есть сетевой диск объемом 1 Тб с различными типами файлов, из-за ограниченности объема его приходится постоянно чистить вручную. Идея такая - с помощью Python проходить по всему диску, на выходе получать имя файла(Полный путь) и размер, в html документе чтобы строка с результатом  была ссылкой к файлу.

Comment: Задача слишком большая. Разделите ее на части и делайте. Например: 1) получение списка файлов 2) определение размера файлов  3) сортировка списка по размеру 4) генерация html файла с описанием списка файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу [этот вариант генерации](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/092b2116f565267e34fa0998d151faf2d11e8f45/generate_report_on__list_of_files.py):

```
import os
from os.path import join
import time


def get_files_info(dir_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
        for file_name in files:
            abs_file_name = join(root, file_name)

            yield abs_file_name, os.stat(abs_file_name)


def sizeof_fmt(num):
    for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB']:
        if num < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (num, x)

        num /= 1024.0

    return "%3.1f %s" % (num, 'TB')


def get_date_as_string(dt):
    return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %m.%d.%y', time.gmtime(dt))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir_name = r"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office"

    # Сортировка по размеру
    files_sorted_by_size = sorted(get_files_info(dir_name), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1].st_size)

    # # Без сортировки
    # files_sorted_by_size = get_files_info(dir_name)

    # Сохраняем в HTML файл
    with open('result.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('''
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
                <style>
                    /* Добавление сетки таблицы */
                    table {
                        border-collapse: collapse; /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
                    }
                    td, th {
                        padding: 3px; /* Поля вокруг содержимого таблицы */
                        border: 1px solid black; /* Параметры рамки */
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
        ''')

        f.write('<capture>{}</capture>'.format(dir_name))

        f.write('<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>'.format('FILE NAME', 'SIZE', 'LAST MODIFICATION'))

        for file_name, file_stat in files_sorted_by_size:
            f.write('<tr>')

            f.write('<td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td>'.format(
                '<a href="file://{f}">{f}</a>'.format(f=file_name),
                sizeof_fmt(file_stat.st_size),
                get_date_as_string(file_stat.st_mtime)
            ))

            f.write('</tr>')

        f.write('''
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
        ''')
```

Скриншот (размер 80%):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** как видно по коду, генерации HTML может код несколько усложнить, поэтому для упрощения можно использовать шаблонизатор для генерации текста – [jinja](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os, time


def _get_files(path: str):
    """проходить по всему диску, на выходе получать имя файла(Полный путь)"""
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:  # файлы
            full_name = os.path.join(root, file)
            yield full_name
        for folder in dirs:  # поддиректории
            p = os.path.join(root, folder)
            normpath = os.path.normpath(p)
            yield from _get_files(normpath)  # рекурсия


def get_files(path: str):
    for file in _get_files(path):
        size = os.path.getsize(file)  # размер
        time_create = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %m.%d.%y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
        yield size, file, time_create  # порядок сортировки, размер идет первым


if __name__ == '__main__':
    it = get_files('c:\\SCR\\STAND\\')
    files = sorted(it)  # Сортировка списка файлов по размеру

    with open('_test.html', 'w') as f:  # в html документе
        f.write('<HTML>')
        for (size, file, time_create) in files:  # чтобы строка с результатом была ссылкой к файлу.
            lk = '<a href="file://{f}">{f}</BR>{t}</BR>{s}</a></BR></BR>'.format(f=file, s=size, t=time_create)
            f.write(lk)
        f.write('</HTML>')
```

Comment: Выходит, что `_get_files` -- рекурсивный генератор?

Comment: да, подкаталоги каталога

Comment: Спасибо за решение, правда я еще до конца не разобрался как работает код поэтапно)     File "C:\Python36-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not generator

Comment: поправил в _get_files

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, а зачем рекурсия внутри цикла с `os.walk(path)`? os.walk ведь и так возвращает файлы/папки рекурсивно